Why is open(file_path, 'wb') not creating the file if it does not exist?
I am trying to write a script to seperate PDFs where a header appears. Everything seems to be working except for some reason sometimes it will not create a new PDF file even though it should have the permissions to do so.
# Define a function to extract the first 150 characters from a PDF page
def extract_first_n_chars(pdf_path, page_number, n=600):
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file, strict=False)
        page = reader.getPage(page_number)
        text = page.extract_text()
        return text[:n]

# Define a function to identify the header
def identify_header(text):
    # Define a regex pattern that matches the header with potential whitespace or non-word characters between each character
    pattern = re.compile(
        "<header text>",
        re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL
    )
    
    match = pattern.search(text)
    if match:
        return match.group()
    return None


# Define a function to split the PDF based on the header
def split_pdf_on_header(pdf_path, year='2023'):
    # Create a directory with the same name as the file (without extension)
    base_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(pdf_path))[0]
    # output_dir = os.path.join('pdfs', year, os.path.dirname(pdf_path), base_name)
    output_dir = os.path.join('pdfs', year, base_name)
    os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
    
    with open(pdf_path, 'rb') as file:
        reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file, strict=False)
        writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
        section_count = 1
        
        for page_number in range(reader.numPages):
            # Extract the first 150 characters of the text from the page
            page_text = extract_first_n_chars(pdf_path, page_number)
            # print(page_text)
            header = identify_header(page_text)
            
            if header:
                print("Header found!")
                print(writer.getNumPages())
                if writer.getNumPages() > 0:
                    output_file_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{base_name}_{section_count}.pdf')
                    with open(output_file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
                        writer.write(output_file)
                    writer = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
                    section_count += 1
            
            writer.addPage(reader.getPage(page_number))
        
        if writer.getNumPages() > 0:
            # os.makedirs(output_dir, exist_ok=True)
            print(f"Does {output_dir} exist? {os.path.exists(output_dir)}")
            output_file_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{base_name}_{section_count}.pdf')
            with open(output_file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
                writer.write(output_file)

# save path is the file path to this PDF: [PDF example Link](https://cbmanhattan.cityofnewyork.us/cb2/wp-content/uploads/sites/9/2024/01/12-Dec-2023-Traffic-and-Transportation-Reso-support-revision-of-CB2-Manhattan-Street-Co-Naming-Guidelines.pdf)
split_pdf_on_header(save_path, year = '2023')

Output I am getting:
Downloaded PDF: \pdfs\2023\full-pdfs\12-Dec-2023-Traffic-and-Transportation-Reso-support-revision-of-CB2-Manhattan-Street-Co-Naming-Guidelines.pdf

Header found!

0

Does pdfs\2023\12-Dec-2023-Traffic-and-Transportation-Reso-support-revision-of-CB2-Manhattan-Street-Co-Naming-Guidelines exist? True

Error:
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [90], line 9
      7 save_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'pdfs','2023','full-pdfs',pdf_name)
      8 download_pdf(pdf_link, save_path)
----> 9 split_pdf_on_header(save_path, year = year)

Cell In [89], line 60
     58 print(f"Does {output_dir} exist? {os.path.exists(output_dir)}")
     59 output_file_path = os.path.join(output_dir, f'{base_name}_{section_count}.pdf')
---> 60 with open(output_file_path, 'wb') as output_file:
     61     writer.write(output_file)

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pdfs\\2023\\12-Dec-2023-Traffic-and-Transportation-Reso-support-revision-of-CB2-Manhattan-Street-Co-Naming-Guidelines\\12-Dec-2023-Traffic-and-Transportation-Reso-support-revision-of-CB2-Manhattan-Street-Co-Naming-Guidelines_1.pdf'

I am not sure why it would not create the file. Based on my output the parent directory already exists so I am pretty sure that is not the issue.

Is output_dir a symbolic link? If the link points to a nonexistent directory, os.path.exists() will say the link exists, but you won't be able to create a file in the target directory.

It's likely that your path name is too long.  Without special action, Windows has a 260-character limit, and that path is longer.  Perhaps you can truncate the directory name to 32 characters?

@Barmar No. os.path.islink(output_dir) returns False.

@TimRoberts Yep that seems like it was the issue. Truncating to 32 seems to fix everything. I considered that, but did not try it because I was manually able to rename the files to the longer name without a problem. Thanks for the help!

Another option is to chdir(output_dir) and then open(f'{base_name}_{section_count}.pdf', 'wb')

I was manually able to rename the files -- Yes, this is one of the painful quirks of Windows, which dates clear back to the MS-DOS days.  If you do nothing else, pathnames are limited to 260 characters, but there are several "weird tricks" that can extend that to 32,768.  The command line rename command uses that trick, but the stock Python open does not.
